# Setting spark classpaths on EC2: spark.driver.extraClassPath and spark.executor.extraClassPath

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, classpath, maven-3

**Reducing size of application jar by providing spark- classPath for maven dependencies:**

My cluster is having  3 ec2 instances on which hadoop and spark is running.If I build jar with maven dependencies, it becomes too large(around 100 MB) which I want to avoid this as Jar is getting replicating on all nodes ,each time I run the job.

To avoid that I have build a maven package as "maven package".For dependency resolution I have downloaded the all maven dependencies on each node and then only provided above below jar paths:

**I have added class paths on each node in the  "spark-defaults.conf**" as

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath        /home/spark/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.5/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10/1.2.0-rc1/spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10-1.2.0-rc1.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/1.2.0-rc1/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.2.0-rc1.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/org/apache/cassandra/cassandra-thrift/2.1.3/cassandra-thrift-2.1.3.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.jar
```

It has worked,locally on single node.
Still i am getting this error.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve the problem. I have created application jar using **"mvn package"** instead of **"mvn clean compile assembly:single "**,so that it will not download the maven dependencies while creating jar(But need to provide these jar/dependencies run-time) which resulted in small size Jar(as there is only reference of dependencies).

Then, I have added below **two parameters** in **spark-defaults.conf** on each node as:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath     /home/spark/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.7/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar

spark.executor.extraClassPath     /home/spark/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.7/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar:/home/spark/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar
```

**So question arises that,how application JAR will get the maven dependencies(required jar's) run-time?**

For that I have downloaded all required dependencies on each node using  **mvn clean compile assembly:single** in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put all jars files .Just Put your application jar file .
If you get again error than put all jar files which are needed .

You have to put jars file by setJars() methods .

Comment: I know that application Jar is needed and it's all ready in place.I am talking about other jars(Maven dependency).

Comment: put only maven dependency in your pom file . It will take all jar files in in main application jar file . it will solve your problem

Comment: If I do so,it will result in large jar file which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: you can do one thing setup hadoop on your machine then put all required jars file in one hdfs directory then fetch all jars file using hdfs location .

Comment: I have hadoop setup on my cluster.But why I should do that if I have spark classpath option?

Comment: spark.driver.extraClassPath only provide jars to only one machine where your application is running . you have to set executors classpath also . Better will be if you will put all jars file in hdfs and get from there .

Comment: Putting Jar's on HDFS is not good practice and specially when spark all ready has provision for it.BTW thank you so much.Your answers did help me.